# regcmp pattern $0 meaning

Tags: c, linux, unix

I'am trying to understand how `regcmp()` and `regex()` works.  My code is

```
int main()
{ 
    char *newcursor, *name; char *string; char ret0[9];

    name = regcmp("([A-Za-z][A-za-z0-9]{0,4})$0", (char *)0);
    printf("name %s\n",&(*name));
    newcursor = regex(name, "filter:attrsonly:attrs", ret0);
    printf("newcursor %s  and ret0 %s\n",newcursor,ret0);
    return 0;
}
```

Here at line 12 what does `$0` at the end of pattern `([A-Za-z][A-za-z0-9]{0,4})$0`  mean?

I'm replacing `regex()` and `regcmp()` with `regexec()` and `regcomp()` functions in LINUX to port the codes from UNIX to LINUX as `regcmp()` and `regex()` are not there in LINUX.

If I removed `$0` from the pattern only it gives expected results in LINUX on execution of `regcomp()`.  What does `$0` mean?

Answer (score 1):

let me quote [`man 7 regex`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/regex):

```
     '$' (matching the null string at the end of a line),
```

chances are the unix program was using basic regular expressions:

```
    Obsolete ("basic") regular expressions differ in several respects.
     [ ... ]
    '$' is  an  ordinary  character except  at the end of the RE or(!)
    the end of a parenthesized subexpression
     [ ... ]
```

edit: ok, i should have looked up unix-[`regcmp`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/All/3c/regcmp/) too, i thought you'd already have done that:

```
   ( ... )$n         The value of the enclosed regular expression is to be
                     returned. The value will be  stored  in  the  (n+1)th
                     argument following the subject argument. At most, ten
                     enclosed regular expressions are allowed. The regex()
                     function makes its assignments unconditionally.
```

so in this case the `$0` just specifies where the result of the match should go, so you can just leave it out.

Comment: I understand '$' (matching the null string at the end of a line), But I dint understand the remaing part about obsolete("basic") etc.  If it works without $0 in LINUX can I go ahead with that?

Comment: hope the updated answer explains it better. otherwise please follow the link to the man pages.